# Formatting date as year with optional era in Swift

Tags: swift, date, locale, date-formatting

I recently stumbled upon the issue with years formatting in different calendar.

When I want to display just a year from the `Date` object I would simply use DateFormatter with either `formatter.dateFormat = "y"` (let's assume I want to skip leading zeros) or `formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("y")`. It works as expected for Gregorian cal.

The problem I've encountered surfaces when I switch the calendar to either Japanese or Buddhist one.

By looking at the native calendar app on iOS year for Buddhist is **2566 BE** and Japanese it's **Reiwa 5**. We can see that era is before or after the year depending on the current calendar.

I would like to achieve something similar without any hacking like checking the current calendar and setting the format based on this.

When I use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` it seems like every time I provide "y G" or "G y" it will get converted to `dateFormat = "y G"`. Additionally providing just `y` won't adjust the `dateFormat` and add the era based on the calendar.

| What I expect | Calendar | What I get for `"y"/"y G"` and `en_US` Locale | Expectations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Reiwa 5 | Gregorian | `5`/`5 Reiwa` | Era after year which doesn't match native Cal |
| 2023 | Japanese | `2023`/`2023 AD` | Era is appended to the year which is a rare case for Gregorian Cal |
| 2566 BE | Buddhist | `2566`/`2566 BE` | Only this one is ok when passing `y G` |

Is there any way to achieve what I described with any built in function? As I mentioned - switching between calendars doesn't seem correct when dealing with dates and calendars so I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: I don't understand your expectations, to me it looks like you want the formatter to use the given format for some calendars but for others it should ignore the given format and use some other logic? I don't think anything like that is possible without some custom logic, the only way to get adjusted formats is to use the `.dateStyle` property and let the formatter select the correct format based on Calendar and Locale.

Comment: When you use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`, it shouldn't care about order, it just take the format letters, and try to use one from it. ie spaces, order isn't accounted, just the "format letter", and reorder in its own logic.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `.dateStyle` doesn't allow for showing only the year component and according to the documentation: "*If you need to define a format that cannot be achieved using the predefined styles, you can use the `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:)` to specify a localized date format from a template.*"
@Larme that's true, I just gave an example.
Maybe what I described is not possible to achieve without some additional logic but I wanted to know if I'm not missing something.

Comment: This method input string is a template not a dateFormat. It will create a dateFormat based on the locale used. The template only defines which components will be used. The order of the components you pass for the template doesn’t make any difference as you have already noticed

Comment: @LeoDabus I know that, I've already mentioned that it doesn't affect the output. I just wonder why doesn't it take calendar type into consideration when ordering the year and era.